# How to simplify this propositional term $(p ⊕ q) \iff p$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Find a compound proposition that is equivalent to $(p ⊕ q) \iff p$ using only the basic connectives, $∧, ∨, ¬$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Iff, equiv, and xnor are the same thing and are all commutative.  They are just parity checks of truth.  $($equivalent to addition mod $2).$

$$\begin{array} {c}
(p \oplus q) \iff p \\
\equiv \\
(p \nLeftrightarrow q) \iff p \\
\equiv \\
\lnot ((p \iff q) \iff p \\
\equiv \\
\lnot (q \iff (p \iff p)) \\
\equiv \\
\lnot (q \iff \top) \\
\equiv \\
\lnot q\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

$(p \oplus q) \leftrightarrow p \Leftrightarrow$ (Since $p \oplus q \Leftrightarrow p \leftrightarrow \neg q$)

$(p \leftrightarrow \neg q) \leftrightarrow p \Leftrightarrow$ (Since $\leftrightarrow$ is commutative)

$(\neg q \leftrightarrow p) \leftrightarrow p \Leftrightarrow$ (Since $\leftrightarrow is associative)

$\neg q \leftrightarrow (p \leftrightarrow p) \Leftrightarrow$ (Since $p \leftrightarrow p \Leftrightarrow \top$)

$\neg q \leftrightarrow \top \Leftrightarrow$ (Identity)

$\neg q$

Answer (score 0):

So $q$ must be false for equivalency of $p$ and $p \oplus q$ . Hence the answer is simply $\neg q$ !